# Get Value and Position of Checkbox in Word Table to Copy Entire Table to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a Word file with approximately 10 pages and 20 tables. Some of these tables have checkboxes. I want to copy these tables into an Excel file.

The following code copies all tables from my Word file into my Excel file:

```vb
Sub Import()
    Option Explicit
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim lzeile As Integer
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sh = wb.ActiveSheet
    Set sheet = wb.Worksheets("Tabelle1")
        
    Dim Btxt As Object
    Set Btxt = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    Btxt.Visible = True
    Btxt.documents.Open "C:\Users\*.doc"          '*=path
    lzeile = 0
    
    For i = 1 To 20
        Btxt.ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Range.Copy
            
        Application.Goto sheet.Cells(1 + lzeile, 1)
        sheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
        
        lzeile = sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lzeile = lzeile + 1
        sheet.Cells(lzeile, 1) = "Tabelle" & i
    Next i
    
    Btxt.Quit
    Set Btxt = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set sh = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

It does not copy checkboxes or the value (0 = not checked / 1 = checked) of the checkbox.
I can write the value of a checkbox into a cell in my excel sheet with this line:

```
sheet.Cells(j, 10) = Btxt.ActiveDocument.Tables(i).FormFields.Item("Kontrollkästchen" & j).Result
```

With a loop j over all "Kontrollkästchen" (german translation of contentcontrol or formfield item) so basically the name of all formfield items in this Word file.
How can I get the position of these formfield items or identify which formfield item / ContentControl is in which table?

I tried to go through all rows and columns in each table because none of them are larger than 10x10. But I can´t find a way to check if a checkbox is maybe in table 3 on column 5 row 5 and then read the name of this checkbox to a safe the value (0 / 1) in the Excel cell on the same position in my copied table.

Comment: This needs more information and thought from you. According to the last code snippet, these are legacy form fields; that implies the document is *protected as a form*, which can affect how the code needs to work. Is that the case? If yes, is there password protection? The most straight-forward approach would be to convert the checkboxes to the value you want to use in Excel, before copying the tables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it is the case u described but there is no password protection for the word file. As macropod commented below I will try do replace the checkboxes by the numerical value but I got problems with the ".Range" and ".Delete" commands as mentioned below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution depends on whether they're formfields or content controls.

Assuming they're formfields:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  For i = .FormFields.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .FormFields(i)
      If .Type = wdFieldFormCheckBox Then
        j = Abs(.CheckBox.Value)
        Set Rng = .Range
        .Delete
        Rng.Text = j
      End If
    End With
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

Assuming they're content controls:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  For i = .ContentControls.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .ContentControls(i)
      If .Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then
        j = Abs(.Checked)
        Set Rng = .Range
        .Delete
        Rng.Text = j
      End If
    End With
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i don´t really get it. How can this code identify if for example content control 8 is part of table 3 on position row 4 - column 5?
What I see is that you loop over all content control checkboxes and set their range into the "Rng" variable but what is this .delete for ?

Comment: Did you *try* the code? It doesn't need to know what cells the checkboxes are in; it simply replaces them with the numerical values.

Comment: Now I´m sure that formfields been used.
Just to clarify what the Code should do is looping through all formfield checkboxes, copy the numerical value and replace the checkbox in the Word file with the numerical value on the exact same position. Am I correct?
Because i checked the code line by line and there seems to be a problem with the ".Range" and ".Delete" part. If I print out the ".Range" part for each formfield it just prints this sign "┴". Do you know what this means?
And I also need to use .Type = 71 instead of .Type = wdContentControlCheckBox.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity and clarity, the sample code below leaves out the parts having to do with Excel, as well as creating the instance of the Word Application. It shows only how to access the Word document's checkboxes and convert those to static values.

At the end, also, the document is closed *without saving changes*, which means forms protection and the checkboxes should be left intact - the macro will not have affected them.

Note: You should have `Option Explicit` at the top of the code page, not inside a "Sub".

**How it works**

The document to be processed is opened and at that moment set to an object (`doc`). Use this instead of `ActiveDocument` as it will be much clearer and, in case the user would try to do something, won't affect macro execution.

If the document has forms protection, this must be turned off in order to delete the checkboxes and insert static values.

Then all the form fields are looped. If they are checkboxes, the value is determined, the checkbox removed and the value assigned to the range the checkbox occupied.

After this has completed comes the code to transfer data to Excel. Then the document is closed without saving changes.

```
Sub ConvertCheckBoxesToValues()
    Dim ff As Object    ' Word.FormField
    Dim doc As Object   ' Word.Document
    Dim cbValue As String
    Dim rngFF As Object ' Word.Range

    Set doc = Btxt.Documents.Open("C:\Users\*.doc")         '*=path
    If doc.ProtectionType <> -1 Then   'wdNoProtection
        doc.Unprotect
    End If

    For Each ff In doc.FormFields
        If ff.Type = 71 Then  'wdFieldFormCheckBox 
            If ff.CheckBox.value = True Then
                cbValue = "1"
            Else
                cbValue = "0"
            End If
            Set rngFF = ff.Range
            ff.Delete
            rngFF = cbValue
        End If
    Next

    'Transfer the information to Excel, then

    doc.Close 0  'wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so so much Cindy! This code works perfectly and it is also very good explained! It really helps me alot.